# Is there a way to sweep through floats in python using a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to sweep through values of pi/24 to pi/2 in steps of pi/24. Currently I'm getting an error, with float  object not being able to be interpreted as an integer. Is there any work around to this?

Sample of my code:

```
for theta in range(np.pi/24,np.pi/2,np.pi/24):
    v_initial_x = np.cos(theta)*velocity
    v_initial_y = np.sin(theta)*velocity
```

Comment: Pythons `range` can only work with integers. If you can use numpy, you can try: `numpy.linspace`

Comment: pi/24 is not a number that can be accurately represented as a floating-point value, so if this construct were allowed, the value would get increasingly inaccurate with each iteration.  You need to restructure it as an integer loop - perhaps `for i in range(1, 13)`, and then `theta = i * np.pi / 24` inside the loop.  That way, the error stays bounded.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the built-in function `range` only takes integers. You can use numpy like so:

```
for theta in np.arange(np.pi/24, np.pi/2, np.pi/24):
    ''' Do your stuff here '''
```

Remember that the stop value is excluded from the range, so if you want to include that in your calculation, then you will have to add `np.pi/24` to your stop value.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
import numpy as np
velocity = 4.0
for theta in range(1, 13):
    v_initial_x = np.cos((np.pi*theta)/24) * velocity
    v_initial_y = np.sin((np.pi*theta)/24) * velocity
    print(f"vx - {round(v_initial_y, 2):<10} vy - {round(v_initial_x, 2)}")

vx - 0.52       vy - 3.97
vx - 1.04       vy - 3.86
vx - 1.53       vy - 3.7
vx - 2.0        vy - 3.46
vx - 2.44       vy - 3.17
vx - 2.83       vy - 2.83
vx - 3.17       vy - 2.44
vx - 3.46       vy - 2.0
vx - 3.7        vy - 1.53
vx - 3.86       vy - 1.04
vx - 3.97       vy - 0.52
vx - 4.0        vy - 0.0
```